# Scan and repair corrupted my Visual studio project

Tags: c#, visual-studio, monogame, corruption

So i'm a programmer who's making a game on visual studio. I save my game on a USB so i can take it everywhere. Unfortunately, i left my USB in my home and when i booted up my PC, it did a scan and repair on my USB (drive (i)). so ,when I tried to open my game it failed and when i looked in the folder, it showed a file called FOUND.000, and my actual folder that had my project in was converted into a file.
I really unsure about what to do. i just want to know if there anything or anyway to restore the .CHK files into normal files

Comment: seems it has corrupted. Try to show any hidden folders, see if they are hiding

Comment: Use source control.

Comment: Sorry for your data loss, but this is not a question for SO. And now you know why backups are so important.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think John is right I had the similar problem a few months ago and this solution has worked for me, all of my files were hidden after an antivirus scan and this made them visible.

http://visihow.com/Show_Hidden_Files_Using_Command_Prompt

Edit: following the instructions here "might" help you restore your data:
https://www.howtogeek.com/282798/what-are-the-found000-folder-and-file0000chk-file-in-windows/

Comment: i did what you said but there are its not restored all the files.  the folder that my game was in converted into a 8kb file, there  is another file called FOUND.000 which contains a load of .CHK files and some other file called BOOTTEX.LOG.

Comment: I googled a bit and found that BOOTEX.LOG might be a corrupted file, or potential virus infested file, the sources all tell the different stories. It might be the reason why your application will not open, to avoid problems like this in the future i recommend putting your files in and archive like .rar or .zip as they are very low priority targets for viruses and they cannot get corrupted unless you archive them improperly or incompletely transfer them from device A to device B

Comment: i downloaded unchk and it recognised the files but when i go to the place where i wanted the restored files to go, nothing showed up. i think it might be saved to a different place or it doesn't support the .sln format (because that the format for projects in VS)